# Remove all values from a binary tree smaller/greater than a given value in C?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, nodes, free

Basically what I'm trying to do is remove all nodes from a binary tree that have a value lesser than the one passed through the function argument. I wrote an implementation but it doesn't seem to be working 100% correct.It does remove some nodes with a lesser value, but not all. Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help. :-)

The code of the function is given here below :

```
NODE* removeBelowGivenValue(NODE** root, unsigned key)
{
    if (*root == NULL)
        return *root;
    (*root)->left = removeBelowGivenValue(&(*root)->left, key);
    (*root)->right = removeBelowGivenValue(&(*root)->right, key);
    if ((*root)->data.numOfPoints < key)
    {
        NODE* rightChild = (*root)->right;
        free(*root);
        *root=NULL;
        return rightChild;
    }
    return *root;
}

typedef struct
{
    char index[12];
    char firstName[21], lastName[21];
    unsigned numOfPoints;
}STUDENT;

typedef struct node
{
    STUDENT data;
    struct node* left, *right;
}NODE;
```

Comment: Please show a MCVE. I can't see `removeAndWrite()` and `NODE`, for instance.

Comment: One basic requirement when deleting nodes from trees/linked lists is to remember the next pointer(s) before you do the deletions/modifications.

Comment: @lorro I have uploaded the structs used above, and renamed the removeAndWrite() function, which was the previous name for the removeBelowGivenValue() function.

Comment: @MikelF I know, that's why I came here seeking for help.

Comment: Write a function that can correctly remove either the left or right child node of a root node. Notice that you will have to reattach the children of the removed node to the tree under the root somehow. Once that function is written, then you can solve this one.

Comment: ... and the tree that breaks it?

Comment: @jhx The tree is sorted, but it is not balanced.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a binary search tree, all nodes to the left of the current node are of a lesser value, while all nodes to the right are greater. Equal nodes go in whichever direction you choose. For your task, you need to traverse until you find your pivot, aka the node which is greater than your value.

For each node that you find, starting with the top, that is less than your target value, you need to:

1. Preserve the right child node.
2. Traverse the left tree, deleting every node.
3. Delete the top node where you started the process.
4. Move to the remaining right node and repeat.

When you find a node that is greater than your key value, you start moving down the left side from that node, until you find a node with a lower value. At that point, you repeat the above steps until you reach a point where there are no lesser nodes left.

If your tree is unsorted, I am not certain of how you'd approach the problem.

Please bear in mind that your entry point will need to be `NODE **` rather than `NODE *` as you may need to delete the root node and change the pointer to a new root.

Comment: A binary tree is a tree where each node got 2/1/0 children. It does'nt have to be a binary search tree.

Comment: @TonyTannous The tree in his case is sorted, but your point is well made.

Comment: We actually don't know if the tree is sorted by the same criteria being used to decide deletion. For example, the tree may be binary indexed by last name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty generic method of removing a node from a tree. The method below assumes you want to preserve the *in order traversal* order, which means that all other nodes (besides the one removed) will still appear in the same relative order after the removal as they had appeared before the removal in an in order traversal of the binary tree.

First, the function signature will take the node to be removed, and its parent as parameters. Let's establish the preconditions.

```
NODE *
removeNode (NODE *node, NODE *parent)
{
    NODE **from;
    assert(parent);
    assert(parent->left == node || parent->right == node);
    from = (parent->left == node) ? &parent->left : &parent->right;
    /*...*/
}
```

First, the easy case is if the node has at most one child. Then, that child is adopted by the parent, and the node can be removed.

```
    if (node->left == NULL || node->right == NULL) {
        *from = node->left ? node->left : node->right;
        node->left = node->right = NULL;
        return node; /* caller frees the node */
    }
```

Otherwise, the node is a completely interior node that needs both its subtrees preserved. One way to accomplish this is to attach the left subtree of to the left of the right subtree. To do that, we need to find the leftmost node of the right subtree.

```
    NODE *leftmost = findLeftmostNode(node->right);
    assert(leftmost->left == NULL);
    leftmost->left = node->left;
    *from = node->right;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return node; /* caller frees the node */
```

And, `findLeftmost()` is fairly straightforward. It follows down the left side of the subtree until it hits the end.

```
NODE *
findLeftmostNode (NODE *node)
{
    assert(node);
    while (node->left) {
        node = node->left;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Now, that the `removeNode()` logic is understood, the `removeBelowGivenValue()` can be considered. Since it was not made clear that the criterion value is related to the binary tree ordering, the general solution is to visit every node and see if some deletion criterion is met.

To accomplish this, we implement helper functions that prunes all nodes off a tree that satisfy a condition. The helper function assumes that the parent has already been disqualified for pruning, so it is only concerned with pruning the subtrees under the parent.

```
typedef struct prune_node_condition {
    bool (*test)(struct prune_node_condition *, NODE *);
} PRUNE_NODE_COND;

void pruneOneSide (NODE **, NODE *, PRUNE_NODE_COND *);

void
pruneBothSides (NODE *parent, PRUNE_NODE_COND *condition)
{
    /* parent's removal already ruled out */
    if (parent == NULL) return;

    pruneOneSide(&parent->left, parent, condition);
    pruneOneSide(&parent->right, parent, condition);
}
```

We need a loop to perform the pruning because each removed node may actually change the node that the parent is pointing to, and that changed node needs to be tested against the condition again.

```
void
pruneOneSide (NODE **side, NODE *parent, PRUNE_NODE_COND *condition)
{
    while (*side && condition->test(condition, *side)) {
        free(removeNode(*side, parent));
    }
    pruneBothSides(*side, condition);
}
```

Since node removal may affect the root itself, the wrapper to the pruning helper returns the new root. To get the new root, it creates a dummy parent to hold the root, and then prunes the single dummy side.

```
NODE *
removeNodesIf (NODE *root, PRUNE_NODE_COND *condition)
{
    NODE dummy;
    dummy.left = root;
    pruneOneSide(&dummy.left, &dummy, condition);
    return dummy.left;
}
```

Finally, we can implement the originally asked function. `removeBelowGivenValue` needs a less than check as the condition.

```
struct prune_with_key_condition {
    PRUNE_NODE_COND base;
    unsigned key;
};

bool
remove_below_given_value_test (PRUNE_NODE_COND *base, NODE *node)
{
    struct prune_with_key_condition *s = (void *)base;
    return node->data.numOfPoints < s->key;
}
```

Now, the actual function can be implemented by passing this condition to the `removeNodesIf()` function.

```
NODE *
removeBelowGivenValue(NODE** root, unsigned key)
{
    struct prune_with_key_condition c = {
        { remove_below_given_value_test },
        key
    };

    if (root == NULL || *root == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    *root = removeNodesIf(*root, &c.base);
    return *root;
}
```